# rdd.mapPartitions to return a Boolean from udf in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am using Scala 2.11 with Spark 2.1

I have a MutableList[String] defined as variable objectKeys

I am trying to use Spark parallelize as follows:

```
val numPartitioning = 10
val rdd = sc.parallelize(objectKeys, numPartitioning);
val x = rdd.mapPartitions(read_files_from_list(objectKeys))


def read_files_from_list(keys:MutableList[String]): Boolean = {
  // my logic to iterate over keys
  if success
     return true;
  else 
     return false;
}
```

However I am getting the error **type mismatch; found : Boolean required: Iterator[String] ⇒ Iterator[?] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.**

What changes do I need to do to have my udf 'read_files_from_list' accept a MutableList[String] and return a Boolean

Comment: From the [**Scaladoc**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@mapPartitions[U](f:Iterator[T]=%3EIterator[U],preservesPartitioning:Boolean)(implicitevidence$6:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) `mapPartitions` expects a function from `Iterable[T]` to `Iterable[U]` _(Where T is the type of the elements of the input **RDD** and U is the type of the elements of the output **RDD**)_ - Given that, how did you expected to use your function there?, What did you really wanted to do? _(this seems like an XY problem)_.

Comment: I would be having s3 file paths in objectKeys variable. I wanted to read them one by one and convert to orc file format. I am open to changing the return type of my UDF- read_files_from_list

Comment: Many things here, Why the List has to be mutable?, Why returning an Boolean? _(The function finishing to execute should be enough)_. It seems you only need `foreach` to execute your transforming function to each element of the **RDD**. However, using **Spark** just to parallelize a simple foreach on a list small enough to fit in local memory, seems like a overkill to me.
Maybe, you really wanted to create a big **RDD** from all S3 paths and save that **RDD** as a partitioned ORC file?, or do that file by file? That would make more sense, but you may give a look to **Glue** instead.

Comment: I need to iterate them file by file and generate an orc file. i can write my logic in UDF but how to resolve the above error?

Comment: Please, read my previous comment carefully. If you need to do it file by file, and every element of the **List** / **RDD** is a path. Then, simply call `foreach` on the **RDD** with your function. Why do you want to call `mapPartitions` if you are not really mapping partitions. But again, using **Spark** to parallelize a simple `foreach` on a small dataset makes no sense. If you use **Spark** for the transformation that would be ok, but just call `foreach` on the initial list, if you want to execute multiple **Spark** tasks in parallel there are already answered question about that.

Comment: Also, since the files are in **S3**, and you only want to reformat them as `ORC`, and probably you want to save the transformed ones on **S3** too. You may give a look to **AWS Glue**, which was designed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

mapPartitions expects an iterator to iterator transformation. You returning a constant value true/false as Boolean.

Here how you can write the function

```
def read_files_from_list(keys:Iterator[String]): Iterator[Boolean] = keys.map( key => {
  // my logic to iterate over keys
  if success
     return true;
  else 
     return false;
})
```

Comment: The only thing missing in the above solution is that the return type is Iterator[Boolean] while we are returning Boolean. I did changes for that accordingly and seems to be working. Thank you @deo!